# chapter number and chapter title page before every chapter, and every chapter with no page number

Tags: chapters

How  can we insert CHAPTER NUMBER  CHAPTER TITLE before every chapters so that there will be no page number on that page but page number will continue in the chapters. I am using report class file .

Answer (score 1):

Patch `\chapter` to call `\thispagestyle{empty}` instead of `\thispagestyle{plain}`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}

% the next two lines are just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum} % dummy text
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % small page

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want chapter titles on separate pages, like `\part`?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{fourier, erewhon, cabin}
\usepackage{microtype}%

\usepackage{lipsum}%

\usepackage[clearempty, indentfirst]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\thispagestyle{empty}\sffamily\bfseries\Huge\centering}{\thechapter}{1em}{\textls[40]}[\clearpage]
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]{\thispagestyle{empty}\sffamily\bfseries\huge\centering}{}{0pt}{\textls[40]}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{20pt}{}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\label{cha:chapter-title}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```